# Changing screen resolution using as3

Tags: actionscript-3, screen-resolution

I'm not sure if its possible but is there a way to change the screen resolution using as3 ? As in if you run the swf in full screen mode that it displays in a 1024 x 768 screen instead of the pc's actual resolution. (I mean once its in full screen mode)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try

```
stage.fullScreenSourceRect = new Rectangle(0, 0, someWidth, someHeight);
stage.displayState = StageDisplayState.FULL_SCREEN;
```

Comment: Thanks that's exactly what I wanted :D